# $L_p$ approximation of $f \in L_p$ is also in $L_p$.

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Suppose we have the following optimization
\begin{align}
A=\inf_{g(x) \in D} \left(\int |f(x)-g(x)|^p d\mu  \right)
\end{align}
For $p \ge 1$, and where $\mu$ is a finite measure and $f(x)\in L^p$ and $D$ is some set to which $f(x)$ might or might not belong. Let $\hat{g}(x)$ be the function that attains the minimum

Dose the fact that $A <\infty$ imply that $\hat{g}(x) \in L^p$?

Here is my attempt at a proof
\begin{align}
A^{1/p}&=  \left(\inf_{g(x)} \left(\int |f(x)-g(x)|^p d\mu  \right) \right)^{1/p}\\
&=\inf_{g(x)} \left(\int |f(x)-g(x)|^p d\mu  \right)^{1/p}\\
&=\inf_{g(x)} || f(x)-g(x)||_p\\
& \ge  || f(x)-\hat{g}(x)||_p\\
& \ge \left| ||f(x)||_p-||\hat{g}(x)||_p \right|  \text{ where we have used the  revers triangle inequality }
\end{align}

So, we have that 
\begin{align}
\left| ||f(x)||_p-||\hat{g}(x)||_p \right| \le A^{1/p} \Rightarrow  ||\hat{g}(x)||_p \le A^{1/p} +||f(x)||_p
\end{align}
and therefore   $\hat{g}(x) \in L^p$.

Please let me know if my proof is correct and how can I improve it?
Thank you

Comment: what are the conditions on g? the minimum is attained when $g = f \mu$-a.e...

Comment: Sorry, suppose that the infimum is over some set $D$ of which $g$ is no a member. Sorry, I will add.

Comment: This infimum may not be attained at any function from the set $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g\notin L^p$ then the integral is $+\infty$, because if you assume the contrary, then $f-g\in L^p$, but as $L^p$ is a linear space and $f\in L^p\Rightarrow g\in L^p$. Next, there might be no element $\hat g\in D$ for which the minimum is attained and in this case you do not have something to worry about. But if it is attained, then the integral is finite, which means that $\hat g\in L^p$, because like above $L^p$ is linear, $f\in L^p$ and $f-\hat g\in L^p$